# Systematic freezes with Unity on 14.04

Tags: unity, nvidia, 14.04, freeze, bios

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my secondary SSD (primary has Win 8.1 on it).
First of all (it might not be completely relevant with my freezing issue but I think it's worth mentioning) : my bios doesn't look too happy with this. In my Quick Boot Screen, there's no list of drives anymore. The list of drives is replaced with the same message for every entry : "Please select the booting drive" which won't do anything; so, I have to enter the Bios every time in order to boot Ubuntu and switch the Hard Drives boot priority. Doing so, my Bios would sometimes reboot for no reason. Really weird.

Anyway, when I boot into Ubuntu, I'm always greeted with a few "System program problem detected" messages that are open in the top left corner and that I have to click "cancel" to dismiss (up to 10 times in a row, as error windows pile up) and can only report (no more details available). 
After dismissing the messages, the OS will just totally freeze after a while. Completely. I've got no other solutions than reset the computer. So all in all, I can't really use it and I'm back in Win 8.1. There's really no action that triggers the bug, it would happen during all kind of tasks.

However, I'm fairly sure it's Unity related as I don't have any freeze with Xfce or Gnome3. The system is up-to-date.

Here's my hardware, fyi :

- Core i7
- 12GB of Ram
- Nvidia Geforce 660 (with Nouveau drivers activated but I've had the bug with the Nvidia Drivers)
- Ubuntu is installed on a M4 Crucial SSD
- Windows is installed on a M500 crucial SSD
- Medias are stored on NTFS standard harddrives (that may or may not be accessed during a freeze).
- Soundcard : Delta audiophile 24/96.
- Two monitors connected

Any idea ? Thanks !